# Hello World in OpenCV (compiling and linking from source on Ubuntu)

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile, cmake, g++

I'm trying to compile OpenCV from source and create a test C++ program which uses the newly compiled OpenCV library.

Compiling OpenCV appears to work, I followed [this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html) guide.

But now I want to create a test program which uses the library.

I followed [this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html) guide, but and everything *appeared* to work until I tried the command:

> ./DisplayImage lena.jpg

Which gave me the following error

> OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented.
>   Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you
>   are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then
>   re-run cmake or configure script) in cvNamedWindow, file
>   /media/chris/Archive2/Archive/Programming/OpenCV/*sav*/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp,
>   line 550 terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'cv::Exception'   what(): 
>   /media/chris/Archive2/Archive/Programming/OpenCV/*sav*/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:550:
>   error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with
>   Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian,
>   install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure
>   script in function cvNamedWindow
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

[image: terminal]

the mentioned packages appear to be installed 
[image: gtk]

[image: pkg-config]

I've tried rebooting my computer after installing the packages and I still get the same message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it

Looks like I was missing some of the packages mentioned in http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html

even though libgtk and pkg-config were installed